# Swift Optional(3) gets nil when unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm new here and i have a really strange problem.
The App loads data from an external PHP File via JSON,unwrap it and save the result Set in an array. The strange thing is that when the Category is 1 everything works fine, but when it's 2 the Optional value e.g. Optional(5) gets nil.

Here is the Code:

```
var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let users: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonResult.count; i++)
    {


        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary
       // print(jsonResult)
        let user = UserModel();
        print((Int32(jsonElement["Category"]! as! String)))

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if((Int32(jsonElement["Category"]! as! String)) == 1){

        if let FID = Int32(jsonElement["FID"]! as! String),let Category = Int32(jsonElement["Category"]! as! String)
        ,let UID = Int32(jsonElement["UID"]! as! String),let Comment = jsonElement["Comment"]! as? String,let A1 = jsonElement["A1"]! as? String,let A2 = jsonElement["A2"]! as? String,let Question = jsonElement["Question"]! as? String, let CID = Int32(jsonElement["CID"]! as! String){
            print(Category)
            user.FID = FID;
            user.Category = Category;
            user.UID = UID
            user.Comment = Comment
            user.A1 = A1;
            user.A2 = A2;
            user.Question = Question;
            user.CID = CID;
        }





        users.addObject(user)
        //print(user)
        }
        if((Int32(jsonElement["Category"]! as! String)) == 2){

            print(Int32(jsonElement["FID"]! as! String))

            if let FID = Int32(jsonElement["FID"]! as! String),let Category = Int32(jsonElement["Category"]! as! String)
                ,let UID = Int32(jsonElement["UID"]! as! String),let Comment = jsonElement["Comment"]! as? String,let Img1ID = Int32(jsonElement["Img1ID"]! as! String),let Img2ID = Int32(jsonElement["Img2ID"]! as! String),let Question = jsonElement["Question"]! as? String, let CID = Int32(jsonElement["CID"]! as! String){
                    print(Category)
                    user.FID = FID;
                    user.Category = Category;
                    user.UID = UID
                    user.Comment = Comment
                    user.Img1ID = Img1ID;
                    user.Img2ID = Img2ID;
                    user.Question = Question;
                    user.CID = CID;
            }

            users.addObject(user)


        }

    }

    print(users);
```

and here are the printed Values from the Console:

> Data downloaded Optional(1) 1 Optional(1) 1 Optional(1) 1 Optional(2) 
>   Optional(4) (
>          "FID: 1, Category: 1, A1: Ja, A2: Nein, UID: 1, Year: nil, Sex: nil, Points: nil, CID: 1, Comment: test",
>          "FID: 2, Category: 1, A1: Ja, A2: Nein, UID: 1, Year: nil, Sex: nil, Points: nil, CID: 2, Comment: test",
>          "FID: 3, Category: 1, A1: Ja, A2: Nein, UID: 1, Year: nil, Sex: nil, Points: nil, CID: 3, Comment: test",
>          "FID: nil, Category: nil, A1: nil, A2: nil, UID: nil, Year: nil, Sex: nil, Points: nil, CID: nil, Comment: nil" )

As you can see the last Values in the Array are all nil, but when I display the whole JsonResult there are the matching Values.
Do anyone no what's going on ? And is there a better Solution for unwrapping the Values?

I really like to hear from you guys!

Here is the jsonResult:

```
(
{
    A1 = Ja;
    A2 = Nein;
    CID = 1;
    Category = 1;
    Comment = "test";
    FID = 1;
    Question = "test";
    UID = 1;
},
{
    A1 = Ja;
    A2 = Nein;
    CID = 2;
    Category = 1;
    Comment = "test";
    FID = 2;
    Question = "test";
    UID = 1;
},
    {
    A1 = Ja;
    A2 = Nein;
    CID = 3;
    Category = 1;
    Comment = "test";
    FID = 3;
    Question = "test";
    UID = 1;
},
{
    CID = 4;
    Category = 2;
    Comment = "test";
    FID = 4;
    Img1ID = 1;
    Img2ID = 2;
    UID = 1;
}
```

)

Comment: Show us what your jsonResult looks like.

Comment: i add it as second answer.

Comment: FYI: the Swift way to do arrays:
`let users: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()`
May be changed to: 
`let users = [AnyObject]()`

Comment: when i chang it users.addObject(user) don't work anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are listing all the possible fields in one `if let` expression, it is true only when all of them are `not nil`.

In your case "let Question = jsonElement["Question"]! as? String" will failed for "Category = 2".  So the `if let` block won't get executed.

Comment: Thank you! How could i miss this .

Answer (score 0):

how to properly use optional binding and casting

```
let d:[String:Any] = ["a":"A","b":"B"]
let v = d["a"]
print(v, v.dynamicType) // Optional("A") Optional<protocol<>>


if let v = d["a"] as? String {
    print(v, v.dynamicType) // A String
}
```

Comment: When i do it this way every Value in the Array gets nil, i don't get it.

Comment: I add it. i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I came up with. Should be close enough to show you how use optional binding.

```
if let items = jsonResult as? [AnyObject] {
            items.forEach {
                item in
                if let parsedItem = item as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    if let question = parsedItem["question"] as? String,                                 
                       // continue chaining {
                       var user = User() // initialize user
                       users.addObject(user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```